# Beginner tips and tricks

Tags: betting-strategy, poker-strategy, strategy

I've started playing poker (specifically texas hold em) and i've had a string of good luck but still dont profit that much and i want to know some tips, tricks or things to consider while playing that most beginners dont usually know.

Thanks.

Comment: This is just way too broad to be generally answerable in a useful way. Find some good books and read them. Then ask more a detailed question about topics you don't understand.

Comment: Chris is right. Try to pick out some specific areas that you'd like to explore and dig in to the details with each question that you ask. I can promise you, you'll get a lot of help from this forum if you can do that :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just believe in yourself! And one more tip - try to use poker software. It can help you to play better and improve your skills.
For example Leak buster is a good variant. It analyzes your game, helps to fimd mistakes and helps to get rid of them.

Comment: Are there any other solutions that you've found, and want to add, because this answer does sound somewhat like an advert, & that's not allowed here. Do you work for them? I'm just asking because I'm curious.

Comment: I see youre using links to the same site repeatedly. If you won't at least respond if you are affiliated with them, then i'll just be forced to remove the links in the fututre when I see them.

Answer (score 0):

first of all, well don for asking for help, it does make a huge difference. 
If there were only one thing to tell a beginner is that there are two ways to win.
The first one is easy - win more hands than the other guy.
The second one takes more practice and that's don't lose all of your money.

As a beginner, it's generally better to fold than to risk all (or a big chunk) of your stack when you are essentially flipping a coin. (at least as far as the odds are concerned)

So if you have AK against someone who goes all-in, I would typically suggest that you don't call all the time. You are slightly less likely to win than a big pair.

Comment: Winning more hands isn't the goal. Winning more money is the goal. Those aren't the same thing.

Comment: Regarding risking all your stack, in general the advice I hear is that less skilled players should be more willing to push, especially early in the hand (such as pre-flop) if they think they have the best hand, because then they can't get outplayed on later streets...